# How to test class using Read/WriteConsoleW

Tags: c++, windows, testing, winapi, console

I have a custom `std::ostream` that uses `WriteConsoleW` and similar `std::istream` using `ReadConsoleW`.
The code is pretty simple and boils down to:

```
HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
DWORD dummy;
if(GetConsoleMode(h, &dummy) != FALSE)
  ReadConsoleW(h, ...)
```

I would like to (unit/integration) test this. The issue:

- If I redirect input to the program (`echo foo | test.exe`) it is no longer a console so I can't use `ReadConsoleW` so making it a full-blown integration test testing a sample program from the outside seems impossible
- Similar for pretty much any unit testing framework which gathers stdout/stderr so `WriteConsoleW` cannot be used anymore making testing inside any framework hard

How can I still test this?

I imagine either faking `STD_INPUT_HANDLE` so the above `GetConsoleMode` returns true and then putting (somehow?) some input there / getting the output checking for the expected stuff.

OR:

Somehow run the program via some WindowsAPI in a way that `STD_INPUT_HANDLE`/`STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` are detected as consoles but in fact being able to fill stdin from the parent program and read stdout, then check that for the expected values.

However I can't find any resources on that. Any ideas/hints? Has anyone ever done this?

PS: Code is for Boost, i.e. OpenSource if that matters.

Comment: *How can I still unit test this?* That doesn't appear to be a unit test in the first place.

Comment: "This" is the custom std::o/istream using the WinAPI functions. Currently there seems to be no way to approach a unit test for these classes. But I want to find one

Comment: Unit tests do not do I/O, and your description of the issue & tests is doing I/O.  That's why I said it doesn't appear to be a unit test in the first place.

Comment: That's the point: How do I unittest a class whose whole purpose is I/O? I already have tests using mocks instead of real I/O but that last part still needs to be tested.

Comment: The last part that still needs to be tested is an *integration* of two things.  Testing the interaction of two things is done through *integration tests*.  Integration tests are outside the domain of unit tests.  Unit tests only test one thing.

Comment: Ok I improved the question according to that definition(s). It can still be a "unit test" (in a wider sense), if I somehow get to mock the target for WriteConsoleW via some WinAPI functions (got an approach for that) The unit under test would than be just the function actually outputting stuff via that API, i.e. test that the API is correctly used. But yeah, as this is still some kind of I/O it could as well be called an "integration test". Hence the change of the question on how to "test" this, i.e. no matter on what kind of test it is.